# I want to use a 3rd party USB-WIFI dongle

Tags: wifi, pi-4

My Raspi 4 has a custom metal case, which means the on-board Wifi chip has a hard time getting a reliable signal to my router downstairs.  Therefore I want to use an external USB-Wifi adapter and then disable the internal one.

Currently I have three working connections to my router, Eth0, Wlan0 and Wlan1.

Soon I will unplug Eth0 (as I'm only using a cable while I'm setting everything up). which will leave me with the two Wifi connections.

**My question is, how can I *turn off the built-in* Wifi device, *without* disabling the external Wifi dongle?**

The external dongle uses RTL8812AU drivers (github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au.git).

The reasons I want to do this are to keep power consumption down, and also avoid multiple connections to the router because it keeps network routing simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you enable Predictable Network Interface Names (in raspi-config) - this is not essential, but eliminates any possibility of a race condition.

Add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to the end of the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file (but above any other added interface lines) which will prevent `dhcpcd` from attempting to activate the on-board WiFi.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for more detail.

I am not sure if you can just disable the on-board WiFi, but any power saving would be negligible if not activated.

Comment: Nice.  After I turned on `Predictable Network Interface Names` in raspi-config and rebooted, the device names changed from wlan0 and wlan1, to wlan1 and wn19123fe234a (or some hex garbage like that).  I had to use `denyinterfaces` on both wlan0 and wlan1 to get the desired result.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The link explains the naming, which is based on MAC, so uniquely identifies the interface.